# Backbone/ChaplinJS view with various template

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have ChaplinJS View, with template which varies according to the condition.
I try to avoid switch statements, but I think it's messy at this moment.

What can you advise?

```
var SiteView = View.extend({
    region: 'date',
    autoRender: true,
    className: 'date-label',
    containerMethod: 'append',

    initialize: function(params) {
        this.type = params.type;
        this.types[this.type].call(this);
    },

    attach: function() {
        View.prototype.attach.call(this);
        var _this = this;

        _this.$el.addClass('active');
    },

    types: {
        day: function() {
            var source = "<strong>{{day}},</strong><span> {{dayNum}} {{month}}. {{year}} г.</span>";
            var template = Handlebars.compile(source);

            this.template = template({
                day: moment(Chaplin.mediator.currentDate).format('dd'),
                dayNum: moment(Chaplin.mediator.currentDate).format('D'),
                month: moment(Chaplin.mediator.currentDate).format('MMM'),
                year: moment(Chaplin.mediator.currentDate).format('YYYY')
            });
        },

        week: function() {
            var source = "<strong>{{weekStart}} – {{weekEnd}} {{month}}</strong>, <span>{{year}} (н. {{week}})</span>";
            var template = Handlebars.compile(source);

            this.template = template({
                weekStart: moment(new Date()).startOf('week + 1').isoWeekday(1).format('D'),
                weekEnd: moment(new Date()).startOf('week + 1').isoWeekday(7).format('D'),
                week: moment(Chaplin.mediator.currentDate).format('wo'),
                month: moment(Chaplin.mediator.currentDate).format('MMM'),
                year: moment(Chaplin.mediator.currentDate).format('YYYY')
            });
        },

        month: function() {
            var source = "<strong>{{month}}</strong> <span>{{year}}</span>";
            var template = Handlebars.compile(source);

            this.template = template({
                month: moment(Chaplin.mediator.currentDate).format('MMMM'),
                year: moment(Chaplin.mediator.currentDate).format('YYYY')
            });
        },

        year: function() {
            var source = "<strong>{{year}}</strong>";
            var template = Handlebars.compile(source);

            this.template = template({
                year: moment(Chaplin.mediator.currentDate).format('YYYY')
            });
        }
    }
});
```